# Start service with different config

Tags: centos, systemd, services, init.d

I'm trying to replicate an application we have and I want seperate config files for both of the applications.

In detail:
Our stack currently consists of:
Nginx, varnish, php-fpm memcached and mysql.

What I'm trying to do is have for example

`varnish-site-1` service running for app 1

and

`varnish-site-2` service running for app 2

I know it is possible to do with systemd but in this case its a CentOS 6 machine without systemd, how would I go about doing that with init or other method?